# Must linearly dependent vectors pass through the origin?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-independence

Why it says 'linearly dependent vectors pass through the origin'? Why it must hold? or must it not? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Look at the top figure: points (3,1) and (6,2) create a line that passes through the origin. This is the case because the vector represented by (3,1) is a segment starting at the origin and by extension any multiple of this vector has the same property. This is not the case for the two points for the bottom figure; they make up a line that does not pass through the origin. The author of the book could have done a bit better...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your "vector-spaces" tag, I'm assuming all your vectors in question are really *elements* of a vector space, say, $\Bbb R^2$.

Recall that when two points live on a line $\ell$ passing through the origin $(0,0)$, then the equation of the line $\ell$ would be of the form: $y=mx$. But this is exactly the condition of *two* vectors to be linearly dependent. (Why?)

Remark: The above argument does not hold for *more* than two vectors in general.